# extracting json data with curl

Tags: php, json, curl

i been trying to extract data from json with the following format:

```
[{"_type":"pipe","time":"2013-10-25 02:42:51","1_price":["00.00"],"1_name":["name"],"_template":"675fgy","1_purl":["http://"],"_cached_page_id":"te487","1_image":["image.jpeg"],"url":"http://"},
[{"_type":"pipe","time":"2013-10-25 02:42:55","1_price":["00.00"],"1_name":["name"],"_template":"16778f","1_purl":["http://"],"_cached_page_id":"456gt","1_image":["image.jpeg"],"url":"http://"},
```

my following code returns "Array2013-10-25 02:42:51" ie. it only returns the value of "time" cant seem to get the value "1_name"

please tell me what im doing wrong

```
    $url = "http://.../api.output";

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);

    $result=curl_exec($ch);

    $arr = json_decode($result, true);

    foreach($arr as  $val)
    {
    echo $val['1_name'];
    echo $val['time'];
    }
```

Comment: Because `1_name` is an array. Access its 0th element.

Comment: im not a coder so i have no idea what u mean by acess its 0th element

Comment: why are you writing code, then? :) And it's actually not the 0th element, because there's no such thing; it's the first element, which is number zero, because ever since C we've been conflating offsets and indices and confusing everyone.  ANYWAY. `$val['1_name']` is an array.  If you print it out, you will see the very helpful `ARRAY`.  What you want is the first (and, as it happens, only) element of the array, which is `$val['1_name'][0]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you `print_r` the result of the `json_decode`, you'll see something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [_type] => pipe
            [time] => 2013-10-25 02:42:51
            [1_price] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 00.00
                )

            [1_name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => name
                )

            [_template] => 675fgy
            [1_purl] => Array
                (
                    [0] => http://
                )

            [_cached_page_id] => te487
            [1_image] => Array
                (
                    [0] => image.jpeg
                )

            [url] => http://
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [_type] => pipe
            [time] => 2013-10-25 02:42:55
            [1_price] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 00.00
                )

            [1_name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => name
                )

            [_template] => 16778f
            [1_purl] => Array
                (
                    [0] => http://
                )

            [_cached_page_id] => 456gt
            [1_image] => Array
                (
                    [0] => image.jpeg
                )

            [url] => http://
        )

)
```

So, you have an Array in `$arr`, which makes that a good variable name.

The first element of `$arr` has key `0` (that's what the `[0] =>` means) and is also an Array, but an associative one (it has strings as keys instead of numbers).  The first key is `_type`, the second is `time`, and so on.

If you look at the value of the `1_name` key, you'll see that it is yet another level of Array.  It has a single entry, with a numeric key.  If you want that value, then you'll have to index to get to it.  The full path is `$arr[0]['1_name'][0]`.

But you don't want just `$arr[0]`, you want all the elements of `$arr`, so you're looping over them.  That's fine, that just means the `$val` takes the place of `$arr[whatever]`, so you have `$val['1_name'][0]`.  The same goes for `1_price`, `1_purl`, etc.  But not for `_type` or `time` or the other keys that don't show arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your **`for`** loop like this

```
$i=0;
foreach($arr as  $k=>$v)
    {
    echo $arr['1_name'][$i];
    echo $arr['time'];
    $i++;
    }
```